# Can GRASS v.net.iso split between nodes?

Tags: grass-gis, network

Can [GRASS's v.net.iso module](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/html70_user/v.net.iso.html) split networks between nodes on the network, i.e., if I am finding the area within a cost of 400, and there is a line segment with a cost of 800 leaving the center node, will v.net.iso split that line halfway down it? (For the purposes of this question, the center node cost is 0).

Comment: Similar question with pgRouting: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9837/pgrouting-how-to-clip-links-when-reaching-max-costs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, GRASS's v.net.iso module can split networks between nodes on the network when you use the vector length as cost indication.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with v.net.iso at one point, and I believe it does indeed split the line halfway. I could be wrong, as this was a few years ago. Luckily, it should be an easy thing to check though by running the tool on a test dataset!